# firefox add-on sdk:how to read the content of a http request?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

By ussing 'http-on-modify-request' observer I can intercept a http request. I can get the header of the request by getRequestHeader(). But how can I read the content/data segment?

Answer (score 0):

To read the content with observers you have to use `nsITraceableChannel` which makes a copy of the stream content or something like that.

https://github.com/Noitidart/demo-nsITraceableChannel

thats a working example download and try it out.

Comment: What's the difference between nsITraceableChannel an nsIUploadChannel? I have found some codes in add-on HttpFoxService, it seems that nsIUploadChannel is used to read content.

Comment: In the official guides, it says 'Register for the "http-on-examine-response" notification to track all HTTP responses;'. Can I use nsITraceableChannel when I want to read the content of a request before the request is issued and before I can modify the headers of the request? In your example, it seems that the content of request is read after the Channel receives the response. It's too late for me.
Thank you very much!

Comment: No you can't read content before request is issued. That's just not possible anywhere. It doesn't make sense. You actually are in control of the stream. You can intercept it and feedback blank. And only if approve you can send at the end of the stream what all you kept from it.

Comment: Sorry I'm newbie in firefox add-ons. Could you tell me what is stream and what level does stream exists?(I think page scripts/add-on scirpts/firefox browser/TCP-IP stack runs in different levels)  
In this example (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers) , the add-on can insert a segment into the header of a request before the request is issued. Is that really impossible to read the data(parameters) of the post request at this moment?

Comment: Actually I'm writing an add-on to intercept all the post requests before issued and add an special segment into the headers. The value of the segment is on the basis of the id of the <form>(for example, for all the post requests created by <form id=F1>, I want to insert a segment of 'name=name,value=F1' into the headers). In order to achieve this goal, I let the add-on inserts a <input type='hidden' value=form.id> to each forms. Thus by reading the parameter of a post request, I can see the id of the <form> which creates this post.If it's impossible to read the content,is there any other idea?

Comment: Thats very doable. Why do you need to read the contents though? Just use `http-on-modify-request` test if its a post, and if it is then add in your param.

Comment: see here on how to check if its post and then modify it: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/1e6ab66a09b3c32ed49f#file-_ff-addon-snippet-asyncexec-js-L269

Comment: sorry but I cannot open the link. I found no file named 'ff-addon-snippet...' in https://github.com/Noitidart?tab=repositories

Comment: its clickable . its this `https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/1e6ab66a09b3c32ed49f#file-_ff-addon-snippet-asyncexec-js-L269`

Comment: Thanks for your code. I wonder when and who calls the exec funtion with incoming parameters 'holder/url/refer/postData/postFunc'? and the code in line 313&316 is commented, so when to addObserver?
The reason why I want to read the content is that I want to selectively add my param. Post requests created by different <form>s in the webpage will be treated differently. Because http-headers contain no information about which <form> it is created, I need to manually add the name/id of the <form> into the <input value>. Then the name/id of <form> will appear in the content of the post.